np.zeros becomes faster with a very large array size
%timeit -n 1000 -r 7 np.zeros(100000000, dtype=bool)

gives 4.22 ms
%timeit -n 1000 -r 7 np.zeros(1000000000, dtype=bool) # 1 more zero = 10 times longer array

gives 3.13 μs (not even milliseconds, microseconds!?)
How can this be possible? Is this hardware dependent?
